# unable to add jquery class for input type file

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

This is my html element. I am trying to add `btn disabled` class to this, but it isn't getting added.

```js
$('input[type="file"]').addClass("btn disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
```

Comment: Hey patricia. If you right click your invisible file input and choose `Inspect...`, you'll notice that it does in fact have `class="btn disabled"`. The example you've shared with us is working fine. Do you have any errors in console? Maybe a jQuery 404 or something along those lines?

Comment: That's correct code. How have you verified that this is not being added? The inline properties will supersede those in your class names. Remove the inline styles and verify.

Comment: @Cue i have inspected code, but that class is not added

Comment: <input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;" class="btn disabled"> it is there

Comment: @patricia In your actual page, is your jQuery code in the `<head>`? Or is it at the end of the `<body>`? Is it inside of another function like `$(document).ready( ... )`? If you press `F12` does your console show any errors? The example you've shared with us works perfectly, so without more information, we really can't help. It's like bringing a brand new car to the mechanic and then asking him what's wrong with your car back home.

Comment: Can you screenshot the code snippet element here on Stack Overflow so we can confirm you're looking at what everyone else is?  Even in IE7 I can see the class gets added properly.

Comment: @NathanChampion IE7? That's dedicated.

Comment: @Cue I have a dev virtual machine for random, internal stuff that needs to run on archaic software.  It's not connected to the internet and the cost of the hardware/software bundle upgrade is atrocious.  It's nice to use that vs "emulation" via dev tools in the latest IE.  I'm not sure how accurate that even is.

Comment: @patricia I think you mistakenly attempted to edit my answer. Consider editing your question instead :)

Answer (score 0):

For deactivate the input[type="file"] you should  add the attribute "disabled" like this:

```js
$('input[type="file"]').attr("disabled", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked about adding classes `btn disabled` to your input. The code you included does exactly that.

However, you then clarified in a comment elsewhere:

> i want to disable browse button,thats it,but its not working

Adding a *class* of "disabled" is merely for styling or identification purposes. Functionally, it will not disable anything.

To disable an input, you have to add the *attribute* "disabled".

To do this, you can use jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```js
$('input[type="file"]').attr("disabled", "");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file">
```